# Knowing the actual dimensions of a sprite after scaling it at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2D project and I've a particular sprite that when I import it to Unity I apply a 200 units per pixels in the importer and in runtime sometimes I scale it.

[image]

How can I know the actual dimensions of the rendered sprite?

Comment: Maybe `https://answers.unity.com/questions/1042119/getting-a-sprites-size-in-pixels.html` could help?

Comment: Thank you @Johnny that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Sprite width in pixels / pixels per unit * X scale = actual width

Do the same for height to get the size in both dimensions.

If you want to get the width of the sprite projected on the screen then you will need to modify the result depending on the camera size. I think you could just divide it by the camera size.